# Cross-references in a LaTeX document

Tags: cross-referencing

When I click on the link of a reference (equation, image, section...) it sends me to the beginning of the page where the reference is and not to its exact location.
how do I get the link to send me to the exact location of the reference?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

When I click on the link of a reference (equation, image, section...) it
sends me to the beginning of the page where the reference is and not to 
its exact location. how do I get the link to send me to the exact 
location of the reference?

 \begin{equation}
 B=A+C
 \label{eq1}
 \end{equation}

 \newpage
 This is the link to the equation \ref{eq1}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you have a question? (Do you have access to the tex file, or is this for some random pdf file, probably generated by tex?)

Comment: how do I get the link to send me to the exact location of the reference?

Comment: you should show a small but complete example, so that we know how you create the link.

Comment: looks ok. Which viewer do you use?

Comment: I use TexMaker.

Comment: On my system everything works out. But you need to compile the .tex-source at least twice without erasing auxiliary files between latex-runs. If need of re-running LaTeX occurs, a message within the cconsole-output and the .log-file created by TeX informs you about that.

Comment: I compiled using pdflatex. If you compile dvi-file and do some old-school dvips - pspdf-conversion-route, this might go wrong if the hyperref-package is not loaded with the correct driver for the conversion-route of your choice.

Comment: it works on the external pdf file, but not the compilation pdf on Maktex.

Comment: Off-topic: (i) Why do you load the `lmodern` package, only to immediately clobber it with the `kpfonts` package? (ii) Since the `amssymb` package loads the `amsfonts` package automatically, there's no need to load `amsfonts` explicitly. (iii) The option list ``left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm` may be expressed more succinctly as `margin=2cm`.

Comment: What is "Maktex"? I've heard of MikTeX and MacTeX, but never before of "MakTeX". Please clarify.

Comment: I mean TexMaker.

Comment: @L.L - TexMaker is a front end to a TeX distribution, but not the TeX distribution itself. Which TeX distribution do you employ, and when did you last update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your code works fine.
- I have tested (1) Overleaf, (2) Adobe Reader, and (3) PDF-XChange Editor.
- It may be the case that the built-in PDF viewer of Texmaker does not work 100 % but if that is the case that it is a problem of Texmaker and not a problem of the code or the PDF file (= good for you).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

When I click on the link of a reference (equation, image, section...) it
sends me to the beginning of the page where the reference is and not to 
its exact location. how do I get the link to send me to the exact 
location of the reference?

 \begin{equation}
 B=A+C
 \label{eq1}
 \end{equation}

 \newpage
 This is the link to the equation \ref{eq1}

 \end{document}
```